# how to make list of files in directory and process them one by one? - Python

Tags: python, text

i want to make a list of all text files in a directory. then i want to create separate list of the contents in each file. e.g document1=[] and then document2=[] so on. and then by using document 1 and document 2 keywords i want to calculate term frequency and other processes. code is running but list cant be assigned different names as document1 and so on.

```
import glob
import math
import re

a=0
flist=glob.glob(r'D:/Final Year Project/Development process/Text_data_extraction/MyFolder/*.txt') #get all the files from the d`#open each file >> tokenize the content >> and store it in a set
for fname in flist:         
    tfile=open(fname,"r")
    line=tfile.read()
    a+=1
    line = line.lower() # lowercase
    line = re.sub("&lt;/?.*?&gt;"," &lt;&gt; ",line) #remove tags
    line = re.sub("(\\d|\\W)+"," ",line)  # remove special characters and digits
    l_ist = line.split("\n")
    print 'document'
    print(l_ist)
tfile.close() # close the file
print"Number of documents:"
print(a)
```

Comment: This might be better framed as two questions: 'How to get a list of files in a directory using python?', and 'How to convert a file's contents to a list?'.

Comment: Just a side note: you are only closing the last file.

Comment: @JohnForbes these two questions are being solved ... the thing is i want to process each file separately and print output of each file separately

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the list you create in each iteration to a dict indexed by the file name:

```
import glob
import math
import re

flist=glob.glob(r'D:/Final Year Project/Development process/Text_data_extraction/MyFolder/*.txt') #get all the files from the d`#open each file >> tokenize the content >> and store it in a set
content = {}
for fname in flist:         
    tfile=open(fname,"r")
    line=tfile.read()
    line = line.lower() # lowercase
    line = re.sub("&lt;/?.*?&gt;"," &lt;&gt; ",line) #remove tags
    line = re.sub("(\\d|\\W)+"," ",line)  # remove special characters and digits
    l_ist = line.split("\n")
    print 'document'
    print(l_ist)
    content[fname] = l_lst
tfile.close() # close the file
print("Number of documents:")
print(len(content))
print(content) # to verify the content of the entire dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp), I believe instead of giving just the text file name give the path of the directory along with the name structure and for "document1, document2..." use a loop or if number of document file is set use them.

Comment: i want to process files separately

Comment: go here - https://www.w3schools.com/python/showpython.asp?filename=demo_file_open you can see, how to execute each file. Make another function and call this function as you want,.Just do that, I hope it would work. If this doesn't satisfy your question. Please elaborate the problem once even helpful for others..